# Creating multiple binary columns from factor levels across entire dataset

Tags: r, binary, lapply

I have been working with a dataset that currently contains 89 columns including 43 factor columns with varying levels up to 15. I was wondering if there was a way to crawl all columns - find factor variables and break them into binary columns. So far I have been able to find a few pieces of code from my searches online here at stackoverflow but I have not been able to put them together in a proper way yet.

To start I will use the starwars dataset

```
data <- starwars
lapply(data, class)
data$hair_color <- as.factor(data$hair_color)
data$skin_color <- as.factor(data$skin_color)
data$eye_color <- as.factor(data$eye_color)
```

To factor out a single variable into binary I would use the following

```
for (i in unique(data$hair_color)){
data[,paste0(i)]=ifelse(data$hair_color==i,1,0)
}
```

I can put the columns in a list that may make it easier

```
w <- which( sapply( data, class ) == 'factor' )
```

Create the above as a function (I cant get past this point)

```
createbin <- function(x){
  for (i in unique(x)){
    data[,paste0(i)]=ifelse(x==i,1,0)
  }
}
```

Now apply it to the entire list

```
lapply(data[,w], createbin)
```

This isn't working though so any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Why do you need the binary columns? If you're trying to run some sort of model, those dummy variables are automatically created, so that a coefficient can be estimated for each of the factor levels.

Comment: Im mainly working with classification types, neural networks dont like my factors...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to do. Perhaps a simpler sample dataset with fewer `factor` levels than in the `starwars` dataset would be helpful.

Either way, I think `model.matrix` might be the key to your question.

For example, we can first generate a binary model matrix for all `factor` levels:

```
w <- which(sapply(data, class) == 'factor');

# Create model matrix for all factors
df <- as.data.frame.matrix(model.matrix(
    as.formula(sprintf("name ~  0 + %s", paste0(names(w), collapse = "+"))),
    data = data));
```

For the final `data.frame` we then `cbind` the original `data.frame` minus the `factor` columns, and the model matrix of all `factor` levels.

```
df <- cbind.data.frame(data[, -w], df);
```

---

### Update

To illustrate, let's take a simpler example.

```
# Sample data
data <- data.frame(
    x = 1:12,
    y = 11:22,
    z = gl(3, 4, 12, c("factorA", "factorB", "factorC")));
#    x  y       z
#1   1 11 factorA
#2   2 12 factorA
#3   3 13 factorA
#4   4 14 factorA
#5   5 15 factorB
#6   6 16 factorB
#7   7 17 factorB
#8   8 18 factorB
#9   9 19 factorC
#10 10 20 factorC
#11 11 21 factorC
#12 12 22 factorC
```

Indices of all `factor` columns.

```
w <- which(sapply(data, class) == 'factor');
w;
#z
#3
```

Construct the model matrix:

```
# Model matrix
df <- as.data.frame.matrix(model.matrix(
    as.formula(sprintf("x ~  0 + %s", paste0(names(w), collapse = "+"))),
    data = data));
```

Final `data.frame` with binary `factor` levels:

```
df <- cbind.data.frame(data[, -w], df);
#    x  y zfactorA zfactorB zfactorC
#1   1 11        1        0        0
#2   2 12        1        0        0
#3   3 13        1        0        0
#4   4 14        1        0        0
#5   5 15        0        1        0
#6   6 16        0        1        0
#7   7 17        0        1        0
#8   8 18        0        1        0
#9   9 19        0        0        1
#10 10 20        0        0        1
#11 11 21        0        0        1
#12 12 22        0        0        1
```

Comment: This worked perfect! Can you explain "x ~  0 + %s" and what 0 + %s applies to

Comment: @MichaelCantrall In the simpler example, `x ~ 0 + z` is the formula used to construct the model matrix; `0` denotes a zero intercept. `as.formula(sprintf("x ~ 0 + %s", ...))` is the programmatic way of constructing the formula, based on all `factor` variable names. This is so that we don't need to hard-code all `factor` variables by hand; instead we generate our model matrix formula based on all `factor` variables in `w`.